# Updating a dash callback output multiple times

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to show in a plotly-dash app how some value changes over multiple iterations inside a loop. The following code should express what I want to do. Of course returning the `value` for `display` would work, but since the function stops in that case it's not possible to see in which way the values changed.

```
@app.callback(Output("display", "value"),
              Input("run-btn", "n_clicks"))
def run_iterations(run_btn):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"] == "run-btn.n_clicks":
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(2)
            return i
    else:
        return ""
```

I tried using some different function with the same Output and calling it in the `run_iterations` function. Since dash doesn't allow same output for different function I created an alert instead, saying "Done" when the loop ended. The issue here is, that I can't call a function normally when it uses `app.callback`.

```
@app.callback(Output("alert", "is_open"),
              Input("run-btn", "n_clicks"))
def run_iterations(run_btn):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"] == "run-btn.n_clicks":
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(2)
            update_display(i)
        return True
    else:
        return False

@app.callback(Output("display", "value"), Input("hidden-div", "children"))
def update_display(hidden_div, value):
    return value
```

Comment: Can you use the `Interval` component to update the app repeatedly? The callback would have to advance just one step each time, but it wouldn't require repeated user inputs.

Comment: Adding to @coralvanda answer, you could potential have the user click on a button which would trigger the interval by changing ```disabled``` from False to True, and then the interval triggers could simulate a loop.